# Higher-order components in Hyperstack

Tags: javascript, ruby, reactjs, hyperstack

There's a frequent usecase with javascript libraries where you want to decorate your components with higher order components.

For example, the material-ui library includes a styling higher-order component `withStyles`.

In javascript, you would do

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = {
  example: {
    padding: 8
  }
}
const SomeComponent = ({classes}) => <div className={classes.example}>I'm a component</div>;

export default withStyles(SomeComponent);
```

How can you achieve the same in Hyperstack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off looks like there is an [issue](https://github.com/hyperstack-org/hyperstack/issues/153) that you have to patch.  This will be fixed in the next point release:   Just add this method to your `Hypercomponent` base class (`app/hyperstack/components/hypercomponent.rb`)

```rb
def self.to_n
  Hyperstack::Internal::Component::ReactWrapper.create_native_react_class(self)
end
```

Now if you have the following styles:

```rb
MY_STYLES = {root: {backgroundColor: 'red'}}
```

and a component that you want to style:

```rb
class StyleTest < HyperComponent
  param :some_param
  param :classes
  render do
    DIV(class: classes[:root]) { some_param }
  end
end
```

You can do so like this:

```rb
class StyledTest1 < HyperComponent
  imports `Mui.withStyles(#{MY_STYLES.to_n})(#{StyleTest.to_n})`
end
```

What is happening is we are dropping out to JS using the backticks and calling `Mui.with_styles` directly and passing it `MY_STYLES` (just like in the MUI doc example).  The `to_n` converts from a Ruby Hash to JS object.  (When passing params to components this is automatic, but not so with simple function calls.)

Then we call the resulting HOC with our `StyleTest` class (also calling `to_n` to convert from a Ruby class to a simple JS class.)

Finally, we import it back into a Hyperstack component class.

That is a little more work than I like so we can just add a handy helper method to our `HyperComponent` class:

```rb
class HyperComponent
  include Hyperstack::Component
  include Hyperstack::State::Observable
  param_accessor_style :accessors  # this is now the prefered param style

  # patch for issue: https://github.com/hyperstack-org/hyperstack/issues/153
  def self.to_n
    Hyperstack::Internal::Component::ReactWrapper.create_native_react_class(self)
  end

  # our helper macro:
  def self.add_styles(style, opts = {})
    imports `Mui.withStyles(#{style.to_n}, #{opts.to_n})(#{superclass.to_n})`
  end
end
```

Now we can add styles like this:

```rb
class StyledTest2 < StyleTest
  add_styles MY_STYLE
end
```

and now we have a new Component Class with our style in it.

For example:

```rb
class App < HyperComponent

  render do
    DIV do
      StyledTest1(some_param: 'test 1')
      StyledTest2(some_param: 'test 2')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I mean't to clarify with some comments.  Most of the docs use param style accessors that look like this `@MyParam` .  This is going to be deprecated in the future because its too ugly.  You can get the new syntax like I used by adding `param_accessor_style :accessors` to the `HyperComponent` base class.  Just didn't want you to be confused!